# How to merge duplicate object values in an array javascript based on a name

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I'm trying to merge the values of an array based on an object name as below

```
[
  {
    name: "truck",
    id: "2",
    data: [{ size: 1, colours: [{ name: 'red', id: 1 }] }]
  },
  {
    name: "Car",
    id: "6",
    data: [{ size: 2, colours: [{ name: 'blue', id: 2 }, { size: 4, colours: { name: 'green', id: 3 } }] }]
  },
  {
    name: "Car",
    id: "7",
    data: [{ size: 1, colour: [{ name: 'orange', id: 6 }, { size: 2, colours: { name: 'green', id: 3 } }] }]
  }
]
```

The desired result is that none duplicate entries are left untouched, however any items that have a duplicate key are combined as per below

```
[{name: "truck", id: "2", data: [{size: 1}, colours = [{name: "red", id:1}]]},
{name: "Car", variations:[
    {id: "6", data: [{size: 2, colours: [{name: "blue", id:2}, {size: 4, colours:{name:"green", id:3}}]}]},
    {id: "7", data: [{size: 1, colours: [{name: "orange", id:6}, {size: 2, colours:{name:"green", id:3}}]}]}
]}]
]
```

I've been using reduce, and for loops but am yet to find anything that works! (or even close)

Comment: add your code that you use to merge objects

Comment: Ha, that's the problem! I don't have any...

Comment: Sure? What if you want later find a Car over ID? Is it not easier to filter your array by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try a bit before asking questions, also it will be better if your javascript was actually valid  (Sajeeb edited it but before it was invalid).

the following function will achieve exactly what you want.

```
const change = (vehiclesAsArray) => {
  const vehiclesNameToVariations = {};
  for (const vehicle of vehiclesAsArray) {
    if (!vehiclesNameToVariations[vehicle.name]) {
      vehiclesNameToVariations[vehicle.name] = {
        name: vehicle.name,
        variations: []
      };
    }

    vehiclesNameToVariations[vehicle.name].variations.push(vehicle);
  }

  const vehiclesAsArrayGrouped = [];
  for (const vehicle of Object.values(vehiclesNameToVariations)) {
    if (vehicle.variations.length === 1) {
      vehiclesAsArrayGrouped.push({
        name: vehicle.name,
        ...vehicle.variations[0]
      });
    } else {
      vehiclesAsArrayGrouped.push(vehicle);
    }
  }

  return vehiclesAsArrayGrouped;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

> First of all, it is not a valid object. I have corrected it.
>   Try the below code

```js
const oldArray = [
  {
    name: "truck",
    id: "2",
    data: [{ size: 1, colours: [{ name: 'red', id: 1 }] }]
  },
  {
    name: "Car",
    id: "6",
    data: [{ size: 2, colours: [{ name: 'blue', id: 2 }, { size: 4, colours: { name: 'green', id: 3 } }] }]
  },
  {
    name: "Car",
    id: "7",
    data: [{ size: 1, colour: [{ name: 'orange', id: 6 }, { size: 2, colours: { name: 'green', id: 3 } }] }]
  }
];

let newArray = [];

oldArray.forEach(item => {
  const index = newArray.findIndex(newItem => newItem.name === item.name);
  if (index >= 0) {
    const { ['name']: name, ...validObject } = item;
    if (newArray[index].variations) return newArray[index].variations.push(validObject)
    const { ['name']: oldName, ...oldValidObject } = newArray[index];
    const variations = [oldValidObject, validObject];
    newArray[index] = {
      name: item.name,
      variations: variations
    }
    return
  }
  newArray.push(item);
});

console.log(newArray);
```